# Set number of visible tabs in JTabbedPane using Scoll_Tab_Layout?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I'm developing a java application using Swing.
I need to use a `JTabbedPane` in a very wide area with a huge number of tabs.
The `TabLayoutPolicy` I need to use is the `SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT`.

The default behavior is that the tabs fill the `JTabbedPane` for the whole length of the pane.

I want to limit the number of visible tabs in the view, so that the left-right arrow buttons are always visible and I can scroll the hidden tabs.

How can I do that?

Comment: *"huge number of tabs"*  Ughh..  horrid, unworkable.  How about a `JList` in the `WEST` flipping between different cards of a `CardLayout` in the `CENTER`?

Comment: @AndrewThompson : A wonderful suggestion, I must say :-)  Regards

Comment: @GagandeepBali  I thought so.  ;)  So was your answer to the `setVisible()` thread. :)

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson (-:  post that as an answer I up_vote this great idea

Comment: @mKorbel  Done. :)  I've actually hit my vote limit for the day (a rare occurrence), but it is always nice to see a positive number besides an answer of mine.  ;)

Answer (score 4):

> ..huge number of tabs..

That sounds hard for the user to work with. As an alternative, how about a `JList` in the `WEST`<sup>1</sup> flipping between different cards of a `CardLayout` in the `CENTER`<sup>1</sup>?

1. This presumes the outermost panel is using `BorderLayout`.

Comment: +1 for this wonderful suggestion and thankyou for appreciating my answer :-)  Regards

Answer (score 3):

As far I know, it is not possible directly, because most of methods in API are private and not accesible from outside. Even dirty hacks that set fixed length (" My Tabs Name     ") generating variable length of pixels on the screen fail because chars on the screen haven't got same size in the pixels. Possible solutions include:

1) override [JTabbedPane](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/swing/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.java.htm) for settings Tab's title for fixed length

2) put the [JTextField#(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#JTextField%28int%29) setEditable(false) to the Tab title (required some of custom JTabbedPane)